# Is there a way to build GCP Data Fusion pipeline using client SDK?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I am learning about GCP Data Fusion and can create a simple pipeline using GUI. Can we do the same using an SDK?

I searched a lot but couldn't figure out an example

OR

I know we can export the pipeline as JSON but can we automate the import?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to import the pipelines, you can use REST api to import them with pipeline json as body. Here is an article on how it can be achieved.
https://medium.com/cdapio/deploying-and-running-cdf-pipelines-with-rest-1d469a243bd0